# My password authentication is still working when I've done everything to disable it, I properly set up passwordless auth w/keys + passphrase

Tags: server, 22.04, ssh

I can ssh into my server using password auth, or keys + passphrase. I have modified the config file and set passwordAuth to "no" and UsePAM to "no" since I don't have a ChallengeResponseDetection line in the config file (Ubuntu Server LTS 22.04). I have modified chmod settings. I've had this problem for quite sometime, and my home server is just for practice/experimentation. I would LOVE to discover what I am doing wrong. What other reasons could password auth be still enabled for? I even found an init file in the system that could've been affecting password auth and changed that to the proper setting, and still, password auth is working. I do not want password auth to work (as stated 3x prior).

Comment: can you post your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file? You need to set: `PasswordAuthentication no` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` then restart the ssh server: `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide specifics - what *"chmod settings"* did you modify? Which *"init file"* did you change, and how exactly?

Comment: I agree with steeldriver. sshd might refuse to use your files if they are world readable/writable

Comment: so I discovered what I was doing wrong. I renamed my keys when I generated them originally, thinking it would add security, but instead, the server was defaulting to password auth since it was looking for the keys in their standard naming format. It took me some time to figure this out, but it was worth the learning experience! I renamed them back to their standard naming practice but still had issues, so I regenerated a new key pair with PuTty and everything worked fine!